# Are there special permissions in Windows 7 to prevent file creation?

Tags: java, excel, windows-7

I created a program that takes in an excel file and pastes in an image of a graphical timeline based on the events in the document. But when trying this on a PC with windows 7 coming from XP and Vista I was unsuccessful in even creating the image. **Is there a permission in Windows 7 that disallows a java program called by an excel macro to create files?**

Formally it's a 1004 unable to get insert property of image file, but this only occurs because the file is not created in the first place.

Comment: is it being created somewhere under program files (eg "the current directory" for an app installed there, or in the root of C? Both of those are protected by UAC.

Comment: Yeah it is it's being saved into the app folder inside the program files so that the java application can access it. then the image is being created by the java program in the cd. The excel macro comes around and does clean up.

Comment: That was already wrong on Windows XP and Vista - it just wasn't enforced because it would have broken too many old, badly programmed apps. Windows 7 finally forces programmers to acknowledge that it's not 1995 anymore and multi-user operating systems are the norm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An application is not allowed to write under Program Files unless it's run elevated (and you don't want it to run elevated.) Write to a per-user location instead, either AppData if the user should never need to see the files, or under the user's Documents if they might (eg an export that they are supposed to upload or mail.)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Hard to know too much like this when your still in high school. haha